# Sprites lose quality when in Unity

Tags: unity, sprites

Whenever I drag a sprite sheet into unity, it, for whatever reason, distorts. Is there any way to remedy this?

Original

[image]

Distorted

[image]

Comment: I'm seeing some telltale BC5-like block compression artifacts here. What compression do you have selected in the import settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on your texture, the texture import settings appear in the inspector window.... look for Filter Mode... bilinear, trilinear, point. Try changing it to Point(no filter) and that should eliminate any distortion. And what do you exactly mean by distortion? It seemed fine for me when I imported with point filter mode. Anyway let me know if it worked.

Comment: Yeah, I had it set to bilinear. What I did is that I just dragged the file in from my pc.

Answer (score 2):

Click on the image asset in your "Project" tab and check its import settings in the "Inspector" tab. For pixel art you usually want the following settings:

- Texture Type: Sprite (2D and UI)
- Filter Mode: Point
- Compression: None

Comment: Disabling compression worked for me! Thanks!